# ASP getting the value of a variable rather than a reference with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

Currently I've been stuck on this code for almost two days now looking up everything I can on it but nothing I've tried has quite panned out, this could partly be due to me implementing it incorrectly or something else, but I figured I would finally ask. I should start by saying that I'm inside of a fancybox. The value of **true** that I want **bIsError** to be, shows up in console.log, however window.alert shows me that it's set to false. I did notice that the value changes once I run through my code. For example - If the username is incorrect it returns **false** then sets **bIsError** to **true** and displays an error message. However I just need it to return **true** and then give the error so that my code works. Anyways, here's my code, thanks for any feedback anyone will have as well, I really appreciate it.

```
 if (typeof bFirstLoginPrep == 'undefined') {
        var bFirstLoginPrep = true;
    }

    if (typeof $ != 'undefined') $(function () {
        $(".ajaxformsubmit").unbind("click");
        $(".ajaxformsubmit").click(function (event) {
            setTimeout("lfSubmitForm()", 100);

            return false;
        });
    });

    function lfSubmitForm()
    {

        $form = $(".ajaxformsubmit").parents("form");
        response = $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: $form.serialize()
        }).responseText;

        var responseList = false;
        if (responseList == <%=LCase(bisError)%>) {

            lfLoginSuccess();

        } else {

            $("#fancybox-inner").html(response);
            $.fancybox.resize();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Should `bisError` be `bIsError`?

Comment: It should, however it doesn't change the result, there's a few things I forgot to fix before posting when I was trying some things, thanks for looking out!

Comment: <%=bIsError%> gives you the value of an instance server-side variable. If you are updating it via Ajax, it wouldn't work because you are probably making an ajax call to a pagemethod which is declared as static and static methods cannot manipulate the instance members of the page. In order to make it work with ajax, you need to return bIsError as part of the ajax response.

Comment: Yes, as DinoMyte says. Also you could set blsError as a session variable in this script before it is sent to the browser and then the script that the ajax calls can read it server-side.

Comment: I apologize for the late response however I did find the issue I was having wasn't exactly related to anything and I had tried the ways above mentioned before. It seems I was including a file that sent me to a blank page whenever the page was supposed to reload. The answers above did work though and I had tried them before. Once I included a different file my code worked like a charm, I sincerely thank-you all for helping me and I did learn quite a bit from it. One lesson learned, make sure you know everything that's going on with your code, even included files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- DinoMyte

> <%=bIsError%> gives you the value of an instance server-side variable. If you are updating it via Ajax, it wouldn't work because you are probably making an ajax call to a pagemethod which is declared as static and static methods cannot manipulate the instance members of the page. In order to make it work with ajax, you need to return bIsError as part of the ajax response.

- Amos

> Yes, as DinoMyte says. Also you could set blsError as a session variable in this script before it is sent to the browser and then the script that the ajax calls can read it server-side.